# Open a link using onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, href, onsubmit

I have the following mock snippet:

**JS :**

```
function generateLink()
{
  var A = document.getElementById('AAA').value;
  var B = document.getElementById('BBB').value;

  if(B == "1" || B == "2")
    link ='http://' + B + '.' + A + '.domain';
  else if(B == "3" || B == "4")
      link ='http://' + B + '.' + A + '.domain/link.jsp';
  else
    link ='/404.html';

  return link;
}

function showLink()
{
  var link = generateLink();

  document.getElementById("link").href = link;
  document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = link;
}

document.formName.onsubmit = function(){
    this.action = generateLink();
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<form name="formName" target="_blank">

<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:600px;">

  <div style="float:left;"><span>Pick AAA</span><br>
    <select id="AAA" onchange="showLink()">
      <option value="11">Eleven</option>
      <option value="12">Twelve</option>
      <option value="13">Thirteen</option>
      <option value="14">Fourteen</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div style="float:right;"><span>Pick BBB</span><br>
    <select id="BBB" onchange="showLink()">
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>  
  </div>

  <div style="float:left; margin-left:120px; margin-right: 40px; margin-top:70px;">
    <a href="generateLink()" id="link"></a><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Go to"><br><br>
    <input type="reset" value="Reset Selection">
  </div>
```

When I run this code what happens is that the `href` opens the correct `url` in a new tab, while the `submit` button opens the page I am currrently on in a new tab. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Doesn't the `document.formName.onsubmit` suppose to make the `submit` button work the same as the `href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to setup a fiddle with your code, and it worked well enough. But while doing it, I realized I had to move a piece of code around to avoid a small problem, so I'm going to guess that you are having the same situation.
My guess is that you have all your JavaScript code before the HTML. When this part

```
document.formName.onsubmit = function(){
    this.action = generateLink();
}
```

is executed, the form does not exist yet, and the `onsubmit` can't be set (you should see an error about it in your console, too). When you click on your submit button later, the form has no `action` defined, and just goes to the same page (its default behaviour). [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vpbnvzv/) having with this problem.

The simplest fix is moving the `onsubmit` assignment after the form. [Here's the same fiddle, with the relevant code moved](https://jsfiddle.net/mLkv7kec/), that actually does what you expect.

Comment: Any chance you'd know how to make the `link` appear above the `submit` button and not in between the `select` elements?

Comment: Well, it depends on how exactly it should be, but you could move it before the form, for example. By the way, you seem to have two link elements with the same id, if you really need both they should have different ids.

Comment: Yep. Not sure why I had two over there. Thanks.
When I move the `href` outside the form, then it moves the alignment of pretty much the whole page. Currently, the link appears above the `submit` but it changes the location of the two buttons based on the length of the link. https://jsfiddle.net/wo5k9145/

Answer (score 1):

You want to set an action="" on the

```
<form>
```

tag. When the form is submitted, it will submit to the page defined in action="". If not defined, it will submit back to the same page by default.